# Can Java delet class object?

Tags: java, constructor

My code:

```
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OuterClass obj = new OuterClass();
        
    }
}
```

There is a way that i can delet the Class object "obj" ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "delete"? And `obj` is an object, not a constructor

Comment: delet, Disable the option to use obj again

Comment: It will eventually be automatically garbage collected if it has zero references to it.

Comment: No, there's no way and you don't need to do it either.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

> delet, Disable the option to use obj again

You can do this.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        { 
            OuterClass obj = new OuterClass();
        }
        // the field obj no longer exists.
        String obj = "hi"; // this works as the previous `obj` doesn't apply here
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly I didn't DV. 
Secondly can you elaborate what are trying to achieve. I don't think you are deleting the object by anyhow

Comment: @Zahidkhan this "deletes" the reference field, but the object will still use memory until the next GC.

Comment: The better option was to dereference it using `obj = null`; rather than creating a scope.